# nservicebus and azure sdk 2

Tags: azure, nservicebus

It seems that nservicebus hosted in an azure worker role will not work on any thing above azure SDK version 1.7.

Is there any way to get a worker role to work with azure SDK 2? If not, does anyone know when nservicebus will support the newer SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure SDK version 1.8 will be supported in the next NServiceBus major release v4